# How to make AngularJS respond to external request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework, angular-ui-router

My scenario is this:
A user signs up with my AngularJS ui-router/Play framework based application. A verification email is sent to the user email with a link. The user clicks the link, and gets routed to a Play-controller which handles the user verification.

Normally you handle the server requests using Angular $http service and can handle the response with the .success()-method, but in this case Angular is not initiating the request. How can I redirect the user to my login-page (lets say #/login) based on my Play-response, when an external party initiates the request?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The ui-router `$stateProvider` will respond even based on incoming URL. what's the point now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you send in your email should point to #/activation?key=1234 then in your activation controller you call an activate URI with activation key on your server using $http.

The main point is that the URL in e-mail should not process the activation key, it should be done by client in a specific state (activation). If you know JHipster project, this [is how this is done](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/tree/master/src/main/webapp/scripts/app/account/activate).